# R: Error in combn function

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R and just can't debug one error I get:

> ```
> Error in combn(nrow(current_data), 2) : n < m
> ```

I am creating the coordinates calculation based on pigeon racing data.

```
# foreach loft, estimate the lat/long
for(i in 1:nrow(loft_coord)){
#print(i)
# get current loft to calculate coords for
current_loft <- as.character(loft_coord[i,1])

# if n_races is only 1, then dont calculate coord (no info, so we leave as NA)
if(loft_coord[i,2] == 1){
next
} else {
# Get lat, lon, dist info for current loft from races
current_data <- races %>% filter(loft %in% current_loft) %>%
  select(loft, lat, long, distance)

# define all pair combinations of races
pair_combinations <- t(combn(nrow(current_data), 2))
coord_input_data <- cbind(current_data[pair_combinations[,1],], 
current_data[pair_combinations[,2], c(2,3,4)])
colnames(coord_input_data) <- c("loft", "lat_x", "long_x", "dist_x","lat_y", 
"long_y", "dist_y")

# define empty matrix to store estimates coords for the current loft in 
consideration
estimated_coords <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(coord_input_data), ncol = 2)
```

it executes until combining...code is stuck there

Would much appreciate your kind help!

Best regards,
Stacey

Comment: Look at the results of `combn(3, 2)` and `combn(2, 3)`, then look at what `nrow(current_data)` can be.

Comment: Implication: current_data must have fewre than 2 rows

Comment: If you need more help, try providing a [mcve].